# Getting the means of data taken on the same day

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I am new to pandas and am messing around with it by looking at primary polling data. I have imported a .csv and have narrowed down the data to only the polling date, and percentage for a single candidate. I am now trying to figure out how to take all of the polls from the same day and average them out. I have seen elsewhere that the .groupby() and .mean() functions are likely what I need, but I can't seem to figure out how to actually implement them. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/polls-page/president_primary_polls.csv')
biden_full = df[df['candidate_id'] == 13256]
biden = biden_full[['end_date', 'pct']]
biden['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(biden['end_date'])

print(biden)

plot = plt.scatter(biden['end_date'], biden['pct'])
plt.show(plot)
```

Comment: first try `print( biden.mean() )`

Comment: Try: `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='end_date', freq='d')).mean()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) by column `end_date`:

```
df1 = biden.resample('d', on='end_date').mean().reset_index()
```

Or solution from comment with [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html):

```
df1 = biden.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='end_date', freq='d')).mean().reset_index()
```

---

```
print(df1)
      end_date     pct
0   2018-11-06  30.000
1   2018-11-07     NaN
2   2018-11-08     NaN
3   2018-11-09  26.000
4   2018-11-10     NaN
..         ...     ...
435 2020-01-15     NaN
436 2020-01-16  23.775
437 2020-01-17  23.300
438 2020-01-18     NaN
439 2020-01-19  28.300

[440 rows x 2 columns]
```

If want omit missing values aggregate with [`Series.dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html):

```
df2 = biden.groupby(biden['end_date'].dt.date).mean().reset_index()
print(df2)
       end_date        pct
0    2018-11-06  30.000000
1    2018-11-09  26.000000
2    2018-11-14  19.000000
3    2018-11-28  26.500000
4    2018-12-09  29.500000
..          ...        ...
282  2020-01-12  27.977778
283  2020-01-14  28.000000
284  2020-01-16  23.775000
285  2020-01-17  23.300000
286  2020-01-19  28.300000

[287 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `resample` and aggregate by mean

```
biden['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(biden['end_date'])
biden = biden.set_index('end_date')
biden.resample('D').agg('mean')
```

Comment: When trying this I get a type error for the 'end_date' index. It tells me that it needs to be a DateTime key, which it should already be. Do you have any clue as to why?

Comment: It should be because, pandas was not able to detect the column as datetime column. So, you could convert it to datetime using, `biden['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(biden['end_date'])`.